# Can a website see if I'm surfing the web via remote control?

Tags: vpn

I am from Pakistan and Paypal does not work here. I was in contact with a Paypal representative today and he advised me not to access Paypal from Pakistan else they will permanently limit our account.

My business is registered in Dubai but we operate from Pakistan. Accessing our account almost daily is a must and I have been told today not to operate the account from Pakistan.

The only option i have is to access my Paypal account remotely using teamviewer from a PC placed in my Pakistan office.

I am connecting to my PC which is placed in my Dubai office using teamviewer.

Can paypal figure out that i am accessing the account from Pakistan using teamviewer?

Answer (score 2):

No, Paypal should not be able to figure out that you are accessing the account from Pakistan if you are using TeamViewer to access it "from Dubai."

This is provided you do not login to Paypal from Pakistan again, or within a short time period of accessing it "in Dubai."